# Trying to implement multiple ACS support with OneLogin

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

We are trying to implement SSO, using OneLogin as the IdP with our Cisco Call Manager cluster using a single agreement for all the servers in the cluster.

This just basically means that our metadata file contains a separate AssertionConsumerService tag for every server in the cluster.

However we are hitting an issue where in the SAML response the Destination is not recognized as valid.

My question would be, in the case of multiple ACS' used, what would the destination field need to look like in the SAML response? Does the IdP need to recognize which consumer the request came from and dynamically change the destination in the response to be the correct one for the specific consumer?

Right now the SAML response looks something like this:

```
<samlp:Response
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Destination="https://<CUCM_2>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<CUCM_2>https://<CUCM_2>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<CUCM_2>https://<IMP_1>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<IMP_1>https://<IMP_1>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<IMP_1>https://<CUCM_1>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<CUCM_1>https://<CUCM_1>:8443/ssosp/saml/SSO/alias/<CUCM_1>" ID="pfx117d2cec-f554-1fba-ff86-8db77b497e35" InResponseTo="s2ded98fb1a7423ea7bb1fcc95cf5c57ae3bf19684" IssueInstant="2019-02-18T16:06:06Z" Version="2.0">
```

and we get the same jumble for Recipient attribute in SubjectConfirmationData

Answer (score 0):

With a proper cluster, you'd have a single ACS URL and the cluster would manage the user session between cluster members outside of SAML. I've not heard of multiple ACS URLs being used for a single SAML supporting SP. The IdP ( Onelogin ) needs to know specifically where to send the SAML response. I think you'll need to look at your cluster configuration and see whether it can be configured as a endpoint regardless of the cluster instance that initiates the SAML request.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, but Cisco is special, don't you know? :)

I managed to get it working in the meantime and whoever is reading this thread in the future, I can confirm that OneLogin can now support Cisco clusters using a single cluster-wide metadata. But for any other IdP the setup is:

IdP requirements

- CUCM only supports NameIDFormat as transient
- HTTP-POST and HTTP-Redirect SAML bindings need to be enabled
- SAML specification that allows for the definition of multiple AssertionConsumerService tags needs to be supported

Operation

- When setting up SSO, within the metadata generated by CUCM if using cluster wide SSO mode, multiple AssertionConsumerService tags are defined. Two for each server in the cluster, one using the POST method and one using Redirect. Each ACS also has an Index tag, that starts at 0. This is sent to the IdP
- When trying to authenticate a SAML request is sent to the IdP, within the request the AssertionConsumerServiceIndex field is set to the Index of the server from which the request was generated, as defined in the metadata originally provided to the IdP
- The IdP then sends back a SAML response, in which the Destination and Recipient tags are set to match the Location tag from the metadata corresponding to the requesting server

[image]